# Is the Java community underserved?

Tags: discussion, community

I've recently changed jobs to a company that uses both .NET and Java. My hobby (if one looks at my profile it's blindingly obvious) is Python.

I've asked, and answered, many questions in the .NET and Python tagged questions.

Since changing to my new job, I've had a couple of occasions to search for issues related to Java.

I come across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19333674/344286), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19440841/344286) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18987198/344286). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333674/jars-no-longer-seem-to-be-signed-jarsigningexception-found-unsigned-entry). I've asked [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20577261/344286) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575776/how-do-i-correctly-use-pathvariable-in-javaspring) about my [own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20549993/344286).

In these cases you either have a few answers that end out not working, and then it seems like interest just... tapers off.

Do I just have some sort of bias here, is this just "how the Java community is", or is StackOverflow just having trouble attracting the right kind of Java developers?

Comment: Hmmm... I always thought Java was one of the more active segments around here.

Comment: I'd vote for bias. All of these questions are specialized to a certain extend and need some advanced knowledge, they're not in the low-hanging-fruit area of questions that are answered within minutes (except your last example, why is that in the list, it's perfect?). You can find thee "holes" in every tag. I don't think that there is a problem with the Java communnity.

Comment: Sidenote: your first link and fourth link are the same post. Honestly this is just a case of a very specific problem area. Java is probably one of the - if not THE - most active language tags around here. You just happen to be interested in a niche aspect.

Comment: From the stats on [java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers), [python](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) ,and [c#](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers), **C#**: 571,872 questions, 18% unanswered all time, 37.1% unanswered last 30 days, **Python**: 255,171 questions, 15.4% unanswered all time, 29.5% unanswered last 30 days, **Java**: 548,275 questions, 19.9% unanswered all time, 37% unanswered last 30 days. [java] is the #2 tag on the site, and there are far worse tags in terms of unanswered percentages.

Comment: One of the things that might drag it down a bit is the overlap with [android], because [we've had some quality problems there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag) in the same fashion as [ios] and [iphone] drag down [objective-c]. The mobile development gold rush has unfortunately pulled in a lot of people unwilling to do a little research and who want us to do their work for them.

Comment: I had the impression that Java has so many competitors that it's hard to get rep. :) I stopped looking at the java tag because I had the feeling that the majority of questions are beginner type easily being solvable by a debugger. Well, after looking more into C/C++ and assembly it's not really different there either.

Comment: @BradLarson, don't know about it in general, but if you look at the assembly tag, I bet you see a high percentage of "unanswered" question because there are really a LOT of them being addressed in comments. Maybe it would be worthwhile to check the comment to answer ratio as well.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby, my last question was in there because I had to answer the question myself.

Comment: @WayneWerner: I fail to see this, to be honest. nitind provided you with the correct answer, it was not very well formed, but could easily be edited to be an awesome answer.

Comment: To the downvoter - mind telling me *why*?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes&pageSize=30).

These are extremes examples but it's just to show you that there are a lot of good java posts here. You cannot simply generalize a certain tag and say that people answering that tag are not giving quality answers or something like that. You cannot predict which user will answer or how they will answer and I highly doubt that this tag has a majority of bad quality posts.

> Do I just have some sort of bias here

I think that is it. As a .net developer I understand that you can be biased about a certain language but let's not come out here and make such generalizations. I turned to java a few weeks ago to develop my android apps and the Stack Overflow help has been outstanding.

Comment: Maybe I'd have to do some more research - it doesn't *seem* like any of those things require that specialized knowledge. I mean, isn't Spring the most popular framework? I'm pretty sure that I've asked/answered some more complicated .NET/Python questions, but maybe it just *felt* like that to me.